# How to convert List<Person> into Map<String,List<Employee>>

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Here is the piece of code which was written in Java7 and I wants to convert into Java8 by using Streams and Lambdas.

```
public static Map<String, List<Employee>> getEmployees(List<Person> personList) {
        Map<String, List<Employee>> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Person person : personList) {
            String[] perArr = person.getName().split("-");
            List<Employee> employeeList = result.get(perArr[0]);
            if (employeeList == null) {
                employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            employeeList.add(new Employee(person.getPersonId(), perArr[1]));
            result.put(perArr[0], employeeList);
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm able to convert List into  Map<String,List<String>> but couldn't able write Map<String,List<Employee>>. Here is the piece of code which I've written : Map<String, List<String>> result =  personList.stream().map(s->s.getName().split("-"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a->a[0], Collectors.mapping(a->a[1], Collectors.toList())));

Comment: Don’t post this code as a comment. Include it in your question. You can [edit] it.

Comment: This is not the best task for streams. Misha has already provided the best possible answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you were somehow close I would say, problem being that you would need to pass along to the next stage of the stream pipeline 3 things actually: first token and second token (from `split("-")`) and also `person::getPersonId`; I've used a `List` here and some casting for this purpose (you could use a `Triple` for example, I've heard apache has it):

```
  personList.stream()
            .map(person -> {
                String[] tokens = person.getName().split("-");
                return Arrays.asList(tokens[0], tokens[1], person.getPersonId());
            })
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    list -> (String) list.get(0),
                    Collectors.mapping(
                            list -> new Employee((Integer) list.get(2), (String) list.get(1)),
                            Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: You can construct the `Employee` right in the `map` function. Then, you only need a pair (and can use `Map.Entry` for that).

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward way to improve your loop is to use `Map.computeIfAbsent` to manage creation of new map entries:

```
for (Person person : personList) {
    String[] perArr = person.getName().split("-");
    List<Employee> employeeList = result.computeIfAbsent(perArr[0], x -> new ArrayList<>());
    employeeList.add(new Employee(person.getPersonId(), perArr[1]));
}
```

Doing this with streams is somewhat awkward because you cannot conveniently carry the result of an intermediate computation and so you would have to either complicate matters with intermediate objects or just split the string again:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

personList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(
                p -> p.getName().split("-")[0],
                mapping(
                    p -> new Employee(p.getPersonId(), p.getName().split("-")[1]),
                    toList()
                )
    ));
```

Comment: but you are doing `split` *twice*, and you can carry those... via a `List` or a `Triple`

Comment: Like I said, "either complicate matters with intermediate objects or just split the string again".   If you start creating intermediate `List` or `Tuple`, it is most certainly better to just stick to a plain `for` loop

Comment: You can simply chain the `add` call: `result.computeIfAbsent(perArr[0], x->new ArrayList<>()) .add(new Employee(person.getPersonId(), perArr[1]));`

Comment: @Holger I felt it was more instructive to show the type explicitly